# Java Regular expression special characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace `xx*` with `x`.

I tried `string.replaceAll("xx*", "x");`

but in regex `*` is special so I need to give a `\*`
but to give a `\` in java i need to give `\\`

==> finally it should work with `string.replaceAll("xx\\*", "x");`

but when the string contains `xx*` the above statement fails in replacing  `xx*` with `x`

Answer (score 7):

1. You have to reassign the result of the `replaceAll()` call to the string variable - that method *returns* a new string as opposed to modifying the string you call it on.
2. Don't use `replaceAll()`!! Use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) when dealing with literal strings:

   ```
   string = string.replace("xx*", "x");
   ```

Comment: +1 for the only person to realise that this operation doesn't require a regex-based solution. How sad for the others...

Comment: I would like to add: If you really need to use replaceAll() and its regex, but don't want to analyse and escape the first parameter, you can use Pattern.quote() method that does it for you

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. Assign the result of `replaceAll` to the original value

```
string = string.replaceAll("xx\\*", "x");
```

Comment: Surely you mean "xx\\\*"?

Comment: I had to try typing that three times. A bug with StackOverflow, I think.

Answer (score 1):

`string.replaceAll("xx\\*", "x")` will not change the given string, as strings are immutable in Java. You need to use the returned value, for instance by assigning it back to the original variable: `string = string.replaceAll("xx\\*", "x")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.replaceAll("xx\\*", "x");` instead of `string.replaceAll("xx\*", "x");`

This is working fine.

Live Demo [here](http://ideone.com/EjLg28).